# $filter then $project on an aggregation request mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to query my database to get a specific element from an array, then only project a part of that array, here is the code I tried:

```
{ $project : {
    name: 1,
    language : 1 ,
    season: [{
      $filter: {
        input: "$seasons",
        as: "s",
        cond: { $eq: [ "$$s.number", saison ] }
      }
    }, {
      $project: {
        'episodes.number': 1
      }
    }]
  } }
```

I want to only get the season that matches the number, then project the number field only.

Here is my schema:

```
{
  name: {type: String},
  seasons: [{
    number: Number,
    episodes: [{number: Number, videos: [
      {
        provider: String,
        quality: String,
        language: String,
        added: { type: Date, default: new Date(1510272000000)  }
      }
      ]}]
  }]
}
```

My current query is generating an error: MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$project', if I do the filter without the $project after it works, but then it returns a whole array instead of what I just need. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake in your aggregation pipeline. What you mean to say is this?

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([  
   {
        $project: {
            name: 1,
            language: 1,
            season: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$seasons",
                    as: "s",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$s.number", saison]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            'season.episodes.number': 1
        }
    }
])
```

and if you want to return only a single number without the complete array structure:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([  
   {
        $project: {
            name: 1,
            language: 1,
            season: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$seasons",
                    as: "s",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$s.number", 1]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$season"},
    { $unwind: "$season.episodes"},
    {
        $project: {
            seasonEpisodeNumber: '$season.episodes.number'
        }
    }
])
```

---

> Unrecognized expression '$project'

Your second `$project` was inside your first `$project` that's why the error message. Each pipeline is one execution, so you can't have nested pipelines. If you need to have two projects back to back then you do it like that example:

```
{ $project: {...}}, { $project: {...}}
```

and the field `number` is inside the array `episodes` which is in the object field `seasons`, so you were missing that.

Also in your `$filter` there is no need to create a double array. You do this:

```
season: [{
      $filter: {
        input: "$seasons",
        as: "s",
        cond: { $eq: [ "$$s.number", saison ] }
      } etc...
```

that creates an array inside an array. Unless you expect the result in that form, there is no reason to do that. In my answer I removed the nested array creation.